# Tracking frequency of words in an ebay search result

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

Using Python 3.5, what I'm looking to do is to go to the results page of an ebay search by means of generating a link, save the source code as an XML document, and iterate through every individual listing, of which there could be 1000 or more. Next I want to create a dictionary with every word that appears in every listing's title, (title only) and its corresponding frequency of appearance. So for example, if I search 'honda civic', and the thirty of the results are 'honda civic ignition switch', I'd like my results to come out as
`results = {'honda':70, 'civic':60, 'igntion':30, 'switch':30, 'jdm':15, 'interior':5}`
etc., etc.

Here's a link I use:
http://www.ebay.com/sch/Car-Truck-Parts-/6030/i.html?_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=4&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=100&_udhi=700&_nkw=honda+%281990%2C+1991%2C+1992%2C+1993%2C+1994%2C+1995%2C+1996%2C+1997%2C+1998%2C+1999%2C+2000%2C+2001%2C+2002%2C+2003%2C+2004%2C+2005%29&_sop=16

The problem I'm having is that I only get the first 50 results, instead of the X,000's of results I potentially will get with different search options. What might be a better method of going about this?

And my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter

r = requests.get(url)
myfile = 'c:/users/' + myquery
fw = open(myfile + '.xml', 'w')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'ListViewInner'}):
    fw.write(str(item))
fw.close()
print('...complete')

fr = open(myfile + '.xml', 'r')
wordfreq = Counter()
for i in fr:
    words = i.split()
    for i in words:
        wordfreq[str(i)] = wordfreq[str(i)] + 1

fw2 = open(myfile + '_2.xml', 'w')
fw2.write(str(wordfreq))
fw2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the first 50 results because EBay display 50 results for each page. The solution is to parse one page at time. With this search, you can use a different url:

http://www.ebay.com/sch/Car-Truck-Parts-/6030/i.html?_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=4&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=100&_udhi=700&_sop=16&_nkw=honda+%281990%2C+1991%2C+1992%2C+1993%2C+1994%2C+1995%2C+1996%2C+1997%2C+1998%2C+1999%2C+2000%2C+2001%2C+2002%2C+2003%2C+2004%2C+2005%29&_pgn=1&_skc=50&rt=nc

Notice a parameter `_pgn=1` in the url? This is the number of the page currently displayed. If you provide a number that exceeds the number of the pages for the search, a error message will appear in a div with class `"sm-md"`

So you can do something like:

```
page = 1
url = """http://www.ebay.com/sch/Car-Truck-Parts-/6030/i.html?_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=4&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=100&_udhi=700&_sop
  =16&_nkw=honda+%281990%2C+1991%2C+1992%2C+1993%2C+1994%2C+1995%2C+1996%2C+
  1997%2C+1998%2C+1999%2C+2000%2C+2001%2C+2002%2C+2003%2C+2004%2C+2005%29&
  _pgn="""+str(page)+"&_skc=50&rt=nc"

has_page = True

myfile = 'c:/users/' + myquery
fw = open(myfile + '.xml', 'w')

while has_page:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    error_msg = soup.find_all('p', {'class':"sm-md"})
    if len(error_msg) > 0:
        has_page = False
        continue
    for item in soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'ListViewInner'}):
        fw.write(str(item))
        page+=1

fw.close()
```

I only tested entering the pages and printing the ul, and it worked nice

Comment: excellent! i thought that it had something to do with the page, but i wasnt sure since ebay displays 200 listings when i visit the actual website. can i bug you to ask if you know where i could find some sort of link decoder also? i also noticed that there are parameters in the link that seem to only be there some of the time, and id like to find out why. i appreciate your help immensely!

Comment: I dont know any link decoder. Checking the url parameters is something that you will get used to when you start web development. The website dont tell explicity what te parameters do, since the logic behind those are made in the backend, but you can play with them and see what happens. The parameters are separeted by '&' on every url. Can you mark as answered if it helps? Good luck!